# Passing a php json encoded variable to a jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, variables

How to pass  a php json encoded variable to a jquery function using codeigniter? My code

```
 $data['customerlist'] = $this->customerlist->customerchart();
   //print_r($data['customerdata']);
   $data['encoded_data'] = json_encode($data);
   //print_r($data['encoded_data']);
    if(empty($data['encoded_data']))
    {
       $data['comment']='No Record Found !';
    }

   $this->load->view('graph', $data);
```

and in my graph.php;
i have this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 PageViews($encoded_data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `echo` the variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   PageViews(<?php echo $encoded_data; ?>);
});
```

See also CodeIgniter's [View User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html).